# How to test sequentially 2 apps on different devices in one test

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

I have real devices:

- MOT (Mobile Order Taker for Android/iOS app based on React)
- POS (Point of sale, iOS native app on iPad).

Goal: In one test perform actions on MOT device (Android or iOS, with WebView context), then perform other actions on POS (iOS, native_app context).

I am using POM where described basic actions for Mobile device and for POS (separately). Described capabilities for 2 devices separately and if run any of it corresponding device will be triggered, but only 1. Such case does not work for me and I need to check interaction (data synchronisation) between these 2 devices and different apps.

I found that wdio allows to use multiremote for 2 browsers on 1 device and comment: *you can also boot up two mobile devices using Appium or one mobile device and one browser.*

I tried to setup capabilities in this way in wdio.config:

```
capabilities: {
motAndroid: {
capabilities: {
platformName: 'Android',
'appium:platformVersion': '13',
'appium:deviceName': 'samsung xxx...',
'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
'appium:app': androidMotAppPath,
'appium:autoWebview': true,
'appium:noReset': true,
},
},

    posMain: {
      capabilities: {
        platformName: 'iOS',
        'appium:platformVersion': '15.3',
        'appium:deviceName': 'iPad Air (5th generation)',
        'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest',
        'appium:app': posApp,
        'appium:noReset': true,
        'appium:autoWebview': false,
        'appium:bundleId': 'com.xxx.xxxx',
        'appium:xcodeSigningId': 'iPhone Developer',
        'appium:udid': 'xxx...',
        'appium:xcodeOrgId': 'xxx...',
      },
    },
},
```

In this case I can't use `driver.getInstance()` in test file:

> Property 'getInstance' does not exist on type 'Browser'.ts(2339).

So the `getInstance()` command can be used only in the way when multiremote is directly declared in test, when at the same time capabilities for only 1 Android device are specified in wdio.config:

```
it('Multiremote', async () =\> {
(async () =\> {
  const driver = await multiremote({
         motAndroid: {
          capabilities: {
           ...
           },
         },
        posMain: {
          capabilities: {
           ...
          },
        },
      });
      console.log(await driver.instances);
      const motAndroid = driver.getInstance('motAndroid');
      await (await motAndroid.$(PIPNAD_BUTTON_TRACER(0))).click();
    })();

});
```

Now I am getting error:

```
\[0-0\] 2023-08-20T10:46:47.459Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444 \[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.\<anonymous\> (file:///Users/admin/.../MOT/mot-automation/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:790:107) \[0-0\]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:640:26) \[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:532:35) \[0-0\]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12) \[0-0\]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:\_http_client:442:9) \[0-0\]     at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28) \[0-0\]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12) \[0-0\]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8) \[0-0\]     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3) \[0-0\]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) \[0-0\]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect \[as oncomplete\] (node:net:1157:16)
```

I do not understand clearly all background activities. How can I properly implement the interaction between 2 or more devices with different apps?

Answer (score 0):

Example of solution, I found:

1. run a few appium drivers on different ports to use corresponding driver on it:

- npx appium --log error --port 4723
- npx appium --log error --port 4727

2. Specify capabilities:

   export const motAndroidCapabilities = {
   platformName: 'Android',
   'appium:platformVersion': '13',
   'appium:deviceName': 'samsung...',
   'appium:udid': '...',
   'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
   'appium:app': appPath...,
   'appium:autoWebview': true,
   'appium:noReset': true,
   'appium:nativeWebScreenshot': true,
   'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
   'appium:waitForIdleTimeout': 0,
   browserName: '',
   };

   export const posMainCapabilities = {
   platformName: 'iOS',
   'appium:platformVersion': '15.3',
   'appium:deviceName': 'iPad Air (5th generation)',
   'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest',
   'appium:app': appPath...,
   'appium:noReset': true,
   'appium:autoWebview': false,
   'appium:bundleId': 'com.my.app...',
   'appium:xcodeSigningId': 'iPhone Developer',
   'appium:udid': '....',
   'appium:xcodeOrgId': '...',
   'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
   'appium:waitForIdleTimeout': 0,
   browserName: '',
   };
3. In BaseScreen of POM declare constructor:

   export default class PosBaseScreen {
   driver: WebdriverIO.Browser;
   constructor(driver: WebdriverIO.Browser) {
   this.driver = driver;
   }
   }
4. in test file declare driver for second device/app:

   let driverPosMain: WebdriverIO.Browser;

   let MainPosPinpadScreen: PosPinpadScreen;
   let MainPosDashboardScreen: PosDashboardScreen;
   let MainPosOrderScreen: PosOrderScreen;
   let MainPosSettingsAboutScreen: PosSettingsAboutScreen;
   let MainPosTableManagementScreen: PosTableManagementScreen;

   driverPosMain = await remote({
   capabilities: posMainCapabilities,
   hostname: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 4727,
   waitforTimeout: 10000,
   });
5. reassign all screens for app to corresponding driver:

   export const createScreensPOS = (driverPos: WebdriverIO.Browser) => {
   return [
   new PosPinpadScreen(driverPos),
   new PosDashboardScreen(driverPos),
   new PosOrderScreen(driverPos),
   new PosSettingsAboutScreen(driverPos),
   new PosTableManagementScreen(driverPos),
   ] as const;
   };

   [MainPosPinpadScreen, MainPosDashboardScreen, MainPosOrderScreen, MainPosSettingsAboutScreen, MainPosTableManagementScreen] =
   createScreensPOS(driverPosMain);

   await PinpadScreen.loginByPin(1234); // login on device with caps from wdio.config
   await MainPosPinpadScreen.loginByPin(1234); // login on another device
   await MainPosDashboardScreen.openTables();

in similar way you can declare any amount of drivers, but do not forget to run corresponding amount of appium servers and generate new pages using corresponding drivers.